# I am using a for loop to print an output from an input of form but the input form keeps adding itself

Tags: javascript, html

so I am getting an input about the number of children in a form. If there are 2 children then two forms should pop up after I click the button, if 4 then 4. However my for loop is not working, for some reason the value of the form keeps adding itself and no matter how many times I click the button, it infinitely keeps adding when it should just stop when the limit has been crossed.

```js
function numbchild() {
  z = document.form2;
  ax = z.no_child.value;
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < parseInt(ax); i++) {
    console.log(ax);
    document.getElementById('xx').insertAdjacentHTML(
      "afterbegin",
      "Enter student 's name:   <input type='text ' name='s_name'><br />"
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="form2">
  how many children?: <input type="text" name="no_child" size="20" required><br />
  <input type="button" name="test" onclick="numbchild()">
  <p id="xx"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Side note: Your code is falling prey to what I call (on my anemic little blog) [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). You need to declare `z` and `ax`. (You should probably also just parse the string **once** rather than on each loop iteration.)

Comment: thank you. I have worked as you recommended. But what I really wanted to know was if I click the button again, it adds up. The first time it works fine, but on second click it should not work but it still does. I think I failed to explain my question properly. If you run the snippet, put a value of 1 and click the button twice or thrice you can see it keeps adding. But shouldn't the function not work after one click?

Comment: Ah, okay -- I did think maybe that's what you meant so I answered below. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If** what you mean is that using the button a second (third, fourth) time **adds** inputs rather than adjusting the total number that are there, there's nothing in your code that attempts to avoid that. You're **adding** the number of inputs.

You could find out how many there are and adjust for that, see comments:

```js
function numbchild() {
  var z = document.form2;               // *** Added `var`
  var ax = parseInt(z.no_child.value);  // *** Added `var`, parse it just once here
  // *** Get the parent element
  var parent = document.getElementById('xx');
  // *** Get its existing inputs
  var inputs = parent.querySelectorAll("div.input");
  if (inputs.length < ax) {
    // Need to add some
    ax -= inputs.length; // Allow for the ones we already have
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < ax; i++) { // *** Don't parse it here
      // *** Note wrapping the inputs in divs so
      // its' easy to remove them (and that gives
      // us the line break as well)
      parent.insertAdjacentHTML(
        "beforeend", // *** Add them at the end, not the beginning
        "<div class=input>Enter student 's name:   <input type='text ' name='s_name'></div>"
      );
    }
  } else if (inputs.length > ax) {
    // Need to remove some
    ax = inputs.length - ax;
    while (ax--) {
      parent.removeChild(inputs[inputs.length-1]);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="form2">
  how many children?: <input type="text" name="no_child" size="20" required><br />
  <input type="button" name="test" onclick="numbchild()">
  <p id="xx"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: this is amazing! thank you so much. I couldn't figure this conundrum out. It has resolved my issue.